# How to customize facet_wrap's grid adjusting behaviour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to write a function that makes plot using `ggplot2::facet_wrap()`. This function will be called on different data, with different number of levels in factor used in facetting. Something like this:

```
plot_by <- function(data, x, y, by){
  x <- ensym(x)
  y <- ensym(y)
  by <- ensym(by)

  p <- data %>% 
    ggplot() + geom_point(aes(!!x, !!y)) + facet_wrap(vars(!!by))

  print(p)
}
```

Generally, `facet_wrap` does a good job with adjusting number of facets, but I don't like its behaviour with 3-level variable, as it creates 3 rectangular facets and elongates plots:

```
diamonds %>% 
  mutate(cut = fct_lump(cut, 2)) %>% 
  plot_by(carat, price, cut)
```

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to customise adjusting so that it would prefer square plots instead of rectangular one, and create a 2x2 grid leaving one window empty like with 5-level variable:

```
diamonds %>% 
  plot_by(carat, price, cut)
```

[image]

I could probably do something like:

```
if (n_distinct(data$by) == 3){
  p <- data %>% 
    ggplot() + geom_point(aes(!!x, !!y)) + facet_wrap(vars(!!by, ncol = 2))
}
```

but maybe there is some better, more general solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good starting point for square aspect ratios would be to scale `ncol` with the square root of the number of facets. Here's an implementation that puts your three-facet example into two rows.

```
plot_by <- function(data, x, y, by){
  x <- ensym(x)
  y <- ensym(y)
  by <- ensym(by)

  cols_tgt <- 
    data %>%
    pull(!!by) %>%
    n_distinct %>%
    sqrt %>%
    ceiling

  p <- data %>%
    ggplot() + 
      geom_point(aes(!!x, !!y)) + 
      facet_wrap(vars(!!by), ncol = cols_tgt)

  print(p)
}
```

[image]